# Calculus - Finding limit (NOT L'Hopital's Rule): $\lim_{x \to 1^-}\frac{x^2+x+\sin({\pi\over 2}x)-3}{x-1}$

Tags: limits, closed-form, limits-without-lhopital

How do I find this limit?

$$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 1^-}}\frac{x^2+x+\sin({\pi \over 2}x)-3}{x-1}$$

I am unable to factor the numerator to get rid of the denominator. Can someone please help? Thank you!

Is there any other way to get the answer besides using L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: what kind of rules can you use?

Comment: Are you sure the factor is correct? It's even not an indeterminate form 0/0, the numerator tends to $-1+\sin 0.5$

Comment: Did you mean $\sin(\pi x/2)$?

Comment: Yes I meant sin(πx/2)! Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: You can find the limit easily using Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @user296113 Using LH to compute $\lim (f(x)-f(1))/(x-1)$ when $x\to1$? Looks like a logical circle, don't you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{x^2+x+\sin(\pi x/2)-3}{x-1}&=(x+2)+\frac{\sin(\pi x/2)-1}{x-1}\\\\
&=(x+2)-2\frac{\sin^2(\pi(x-1)/4)}{x-1}\\\\
&=(x+2)-\frac{\pi^2}{8}\left(\frac{\sin(\pi(x-1)/4)}{\pi (x-1)/4}\right)^2(x-1)
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{\sin(\pi(x-1)/4)}{\pi (x-1)/4}=1$, the limit of interest is $3$.

Comment: Yeah ! Real mathematicians NEVER use l'hospitals's rule.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Rene, now that was funny!  And much appreciative.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV how did you get from the first step to the second step (the part with sin^2)? thanks so much!

Comment: @Rachel Note that $$\sin^2(x/2)=\frac{1-\cos(x)}{2}$$

Answer (score 7):

One may recall that, for any differentiable function $f$ near $a$, one has
$$
\lim_{x \to a^-}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(a^-)
$$ then observing that
$$
\frac{x^2+x+\sin({\pi\over 2}x)-3}{x-1}=\frac{\left(x^2+x+\sin({\pi\over 2}x)\right)-\left(1^2+1+\sin({\pi\over 2}\cdot1)\right)}{x-1}
$$ one gets that the sought limit is equal to
$$
f'(1^-)=\left.2x+1+\frac \pi 2 \cos \frac{\pi x}{2} \right|_{x \to 1^-}=3.
$$

Comment: such a funny hint!

Comment: As I always tell my students, when you know derivatives, you know *many* limits. But probably the OP's instructor won't agree.

Answer (score 1):

Here we do not use Hopital or derivatives.

Note that 
$$x^2+x+\sin({\pi \over 2}x)-3=(x+2)(x-1)+\sin({\pi \over 2}-{\pi \over 2}(1-x))-1\\=(x+2)(x-1)+\cos({\pi \over 2}(1-x))-1\\
=(x+2)(x-1)-2\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{4}(1-x))$$
because $1-\cos(t)=2\sin^2(t/2)$.
Hence, as $x\to 1$,
$$\frac{x^2+x+\sin({\pi \over 2}x)}{(x-1)}=x+2-2\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}(1-x))\cdot \frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}(1-x))}{(x-1)}\to 1+2+0=3$$
where we used the fact that 
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}(1-x))}{(x-1)}=-\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}(1-x))}{\frac{\pi}{4}(1-x)}=-\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: @Did Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

*Another possible way to do it.*

Start changing variable $x=y+1$; this gives
$$\frac{x^2+x+\sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)-3}{x-1}=\frac{y^2+3 y+\cos \left(\frac{\pi  y}{2}\right)-1}{y}$$ Now, use Taylor expansion $$\cos(t)=1-\frac{t^2}{2}+O\left(t^4\right)$$ which gives $$\cos \left(\frac{\pi  y}{2}\right)=1-\frac{\pi ^2 y^2}{8}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ So $$\frac{y^2+3 y+\cos \left(\frac{\pi  y}{2}\right)-1}{y}=\frac{y^2 +3y-\frac{\pi ^2 y^2}{8}+O\left(y^4\right)}{y}=(1-\frac{\pi ^2 }{8})y+3+O\left(y^3\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.